# Cage holder for large bottle

Tags: bottle

I am trying to find a bottle holder for this bottle.

I am open to building it if need be.

I am NOT interested in buying another bottle.

[image]

Comment: Google "oversized bottle cage".

Comment: That looks like a poor design for a bottle for cycling, because it appears to need two hands to open which means riding no-handed, or using an armpit, or stopping.  Instead, do consider a regular bottle (bidon) which can be used while riding.   You can get double-wall versions, or possibly just a new mouthcap for your existing bottle.

Comment: If it's metallic you should look for some "soft" holder - plastic or something like, otherwise the bottle will become all scratched soon

Comment: @Criggie Stopping my bike to drink is a simple matter.

Comment: @fixit7 Oh - you asked for a bottle cage, whose primary intent is for drinking on the go.  Sure its convenient as a carrier as well, but access while riding is the main purpose.   Is it a vaccuum or insulated bottle  ?

Comment: It's a vacuum bottle. Keeps cold up to 12 hrs.

Comment: @Criggie Even if you don't want to (or can't) drink while on the move, a bottle cage is still much more convenient than having to get the bottle out of a bag or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topeak make a couple of adjustable cages (both branded 'modula') which should go big enough. I've got the plastic one, as well as a couple of cheap copies from eBay. Other makes may also.

Answer (score 3):

Specific product recommendations are off-topic for Bicycles.SE. There are some bottle cages for larger-than-usual bottles, but water bottles for bikes come in a standard size with a diameter of about 2¾" and a shoulder about 5" along its length, and most cages are designed specifically for that.

Comment: Wire based cages are often quite malleable too, and can be adjusted to suit a range of botttles

Comment: @Criggie Unless it's aluminium - which it often is for weight - in which case don't try to adjust it...

Comment: @DavidW You are right. Bending it out makes it larger in diameter at the top but not at the bottom.